# Wrong output when using currency style with NSNumberFormatter

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsnumberformatter

I'm currently trying to format a float from a JSON feed to a number with NSNumberFormatter using currency style.

My current solution is this:

```
float test = 100.50;
NSNumber *number = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:test];

NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];
[formatter setCurrencyCode:@"DKK"];
NSString *price = [formatter stringFromNumber:number];
```

My problem is that the output is 'DKK100.50' when the correct result for the selected currency should be 'DKK100,50' (notice the current result is with a dot as decimal seperator and not a comma as it should).

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't specify the `NSLocale` for your `NSNumberFormatter`, it will use the current "region" in the setting, to set up the currency format (that includes the separator). Your current "region" setting might be a region that use dot as separator, change it to the one that use comma, for example `en_US`

```
[formatter setLocale:[[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"] autorelease]];
```

for example